# Memory bank A failure - where is the culprit?

Tags: memory, motherboard, troubleshooting, memory-error, sdram

I have an ASRock 970 Extreme4 and AMD PhenomII processor. It's about 10 years old.
There are four RAM slots: A1, A2, B1, B2.
After some cleaning and then troubleshooting, if I install any RAM on either or both slots A, I get error 54 ("unspecified memory error").
Both slots B work, and the computer starts and can be used normally, including gaming with a RX590 video card.

My question is: where is likely the problem? The memory banks A are physically fine, inspected. The fact that both fail is puzzling me.

I doubt it has anything to do with PSU as I don't think it would only fail in memory bank A and nothing else. Another component would show failure too.
I doubt it's the CPU because it would fail another component, or during use, most likely.

When all slots are used, BIOS show the correct total memory, and all four slots used.
However Windows and memtest report only the total memory from banks B, that is, BIOS see memories in bank A but don't allow them to be used by Windows or memtest.

Safe to report that it's the motherboard that suffered a electrical discharge or failure with a resistor/capacitor that deals with memory bank A? Is there any other test, check that can be done?
My point here is to investigate what is the source of the problem, even if it's not fixable.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with the motherboard (socket) or the processor itself

Comment: You can also get memtest86 (https://www.memtest86.com/) to test memory.  Make a bootable USB Key, start with it. If a socket is bad, that should show as not being able to test.

Comment: @John memtest see all slots, but tests only the memory from B bank.

Comment: Hard to tell. It appears the memory might be bad, but you may wish to take the machine to a local repair shop. 10 years is past economic repair unless it is just the memory module.

Comment: @John memories are fine because I tested one by one in the B banks. I'll not repair, but I wanted to know what is the cause.

Comment: If the memory modules are fine, the motherboard is then the issue. Up to you whether you wish to repair the machine

Comment: @John thank you, don't want to bother but do you have an idea what in the motherboard might be failing? BIOS see all memories, including in the faulty bank A, and their correct specs. However they are not usable either in Windows or USB-booted memtest. They were working before. It puzzles me that they are visible, but not usable. When tested isolated, any memory on banks A show BIOS error 54. I already cleared CMOS many times.

Comment: Could be the socket connection or a part on the motherboard.